# Free tool like Github for team code management

Tags: github

Is there any free linux application for managing code like github does?
But it should work on local server and team where i can commit and merge the code.
Thanks

Comment: There are free plans for opensource or private projects on Github and Bitbucket. Apart from that, if you are a company, be prepared to pay some money for excellent software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/product/source-code-management/) is an open source alternative to GitHub that allows self hosting as well as providing some additional in built features.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot